# SQL Finding the average time between user-event over all users

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get an output which I don't know how to formulate.

The Case:

I need the average time elapsed between the 1st and 10th event from the same user, and then an average of that time from all users.

I tried writing it, but i have no clue where to start writing the syntax to get the result i desire.

So, I need:

```
WHEN Count(user_event = 10) THEN avg(date(1st event and 20th event))
```

This seems to me to be the logical way. But I'm a novice at **sql** and I'm trying to get this data. But I can't get anywhere near the output I need.

```
SELECT 
WHEN Count(user_event = 10) THEN avg(date(1st event and 20th event))
from my_table
;
```

The average time between event 1-10 over all users.

my_table contains:

```
 ID, date, name, user_id
```

Comment: share the table data please

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: i understand but my tries have been very basic attempts and I cant get an output

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: I know enough to get simple read-outs but thats why I bothered to ask here, because i dont know how to tackle a case like this. Im not a sql professional in any way. I'm trying to learn sql and this problem is one im trying to solve/learn/understand in a course im following. So i would like to know how people approach a case like this.

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and your expected output?